# Having Trouble With Strings, Arrays, and IP Addresses (VB.NET)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, list, ip

I have a piece of code that pings a list of NIST servers and retrieves the time they have. This is the original code that works perfect:

```
'Server IP addresses from 
'http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi - current as of 05/20/2016
Private Shared Servers() As String = {
      "129.6.15.28" _
    , "129.6.15.29" _
    , "129.6.15.30" _
    , "98.175.203.200" _
    , "66.199.22.67" _
    , "64.113.32.5" _
    , "198.111.152.100" _
    , "216.229.0.179" _
    , "24.56.178.140" _
    , "132.163.4.101" _
    , "132.163.4.102" _
    , "132.163.4.103" _
    , "128.138.140.44" _
    , "128.138.141.172" _
    , "198.60.73.8" _
    , "131.107.13.100" _
    , "216.228.192.69"
}

Public Shared LastHost As String = ""
Public Shared LastSysTime As DateTime

Public Shared Function GetTime() As DateTime
    'Returns UTC/GMT using an NIST server if possible, 
    ' degrading to simply returning the system clock

    'If we are successful in getting NIST time, then
    ' LastHost indicates which server was used and
    ' LastSysTime contains the system time of the call
    ' If LastSysTime is not within 15 seconds of NIST time,
    '  the system clock may need to be reset
    ' If LastHost is "", time is equal to system clock

    Dim host As String
    Dim result As DateTime

    LastHost = ""
    For Each host In Servers
        Try
            If My.Computer.Network.Ping(host) Then
                LastHost = host
                result = GetNISTTime(host)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("There was an error retrieving the internet time. Please try again.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Sync Error")
        End Try
    Next

    If LastHost = "" Then
        'No server in list was successful so use system time
        result = DateTime.UtcNow()
    End If

    Return result
End Function
```

However, I'm trying to modify it so I can use a list of NIST server IP addresses saved in a My.Settings or My.Resources file instead (so I can modify the I addresses easily). So basically just go down each line just like the above working code. Except the following code doesn't work like the above code; it just returns something along the lines of "System.Strings[]":

```
'Server IP addresses from 
'http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi - current as of 05/20/2016
'Declares stting that loads server IP addresses
Public Shared VanServ As String = My.Resources.VanillaServerIPList
Public Shared Serv As String = My.Settings.ServerIPList
Public Shared Servers() As String


Public Shared LastHost As String = ""
Public Shared LastSysTime As DateTime

Public Shared Function GetTime() As DateTime
    'Returns UTC/GMT using an NIST server if possible, 
    ' degrading to simply returning the system clock

    'If we are successful in getting NIST time, then
    ' LastHost indicates which server was used and
    ' LastSysTime contains the system time of the call
    ' If LastSysTime is not within 15 seconds of NIST time,
    '  the system clock may need to be reset
    ' If LastHost is "", time is equal to system clock
    Servers = Serv.Split(vbCrLf)

    Dim host As String
    Dim result As DateTime

    LastHost = ""
    For Each host In Servers
        Try
            If My.Computer.Network.Ping(host) Then
                LastHost = host
                result = GetNISTTime(host)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("There was an error retrieving the internet time. Please try again.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Sync Error")
        End Try
    Next

    If LastHost = "" Then
        'No server in list was successful so use system time
        result = DateTime.UtcNow()
    End If

    Return result
End Function
```

The My.Resources.VanillaServerIPList and My.Settings.ServerIPList look as follows (and before you say to check if the lists are null, both lists do in fact contain the following values):

129.6.15.28

129.6.15.29

129.6.15.30

98.175.203.200

66.199.22.67

64.113.32.5

198.111.152.100

216.229.0.179

...and so on; each IP is on a new line

Comment: which programing language are you using ? better add it to the tags...

Comment: Oh my bad. I'm using VB.NET

Comment: Are you sure it returns a string "System.Strings[]"? It's a DateTime object, not a string. Looks like the default ToString() on a list of strings. To debug this program, print each string inside the loop to see what it's actually using. If it still isn't working, you can post that much simpler code without any of the network code. It'll be easier for people to understand.

Comment: Have you tried outputting the Servers() array to make sure your split is working as you expect?

Comment: You can set your My.Settings setting type to `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection` instead of `System.String`. That way you can load your setting into an array like your first code, and you wouldn't have to worry about splitting problems. To put it into an array you would just do: `My.Settings.Servers.CopyTo(YourArray, 0)` - where _Servers_ is the setting's name, and _YourArray_ is the array you want to put it in.

Comment: user1318499, it's not a DateTime object, it's a string and string array of IP addresses. Please review the code...

Michael, yes, it returns System.Strings[], not a list of IP addresses (unless I just leave it a regular string). The problem is it's not properly converting the string to an array...

Vincent, I'll give that a shot in a few minutes, but I believe I already tried that with no luck which is why I went the route I tried

Comment: Then you must've done something wrong, because that method will work if it's done right. :)

Comment: I changed it in Settings to "StringCollection", and I entered this code in my class "Private Shared Servers() As String = My.Settings.ServerIPList". And now it says "Value of type String cannot be converted to String()"

Comment: Yes, the split function returns `System.String[]`, but that doesn't mean it returned the way you wanted. You have to look at each element in the array in debug mode to make sure it contains what you expect. I suspect you had a problem splitting on `vbCrLf`. Try splitting on `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: I actually figured it out. I'll post an answer soon

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I finally landed on:

```
'Variables
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Shared VanServArray As Array 'Used to store "vanilla" list of NIST server IPs stored in My.Settings.VanillaServerIPList
Private Shared ServArray As Array 'Used to store list of NIST server IPs stored in My.Settings.ServerIPList
Private Shared Result As DateTime 'Stores DateTime retrieved from NIST Server

Public Shared LastHost As String = ""
Public Shared LastSysTime As DateTime 'Stores last available system DateTime

'Functions
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Shared Function GetTime() As DateTime
    'Returns UTC/GMT using an NIST server if possible, 
    ' degrading to simply returning the system clock

    If My.Settings.ServerIPList Is Nothing Then
        'If the user modifiable list of NIST server IP addresses IS null (null = TRUE) then
        'Put pre-stored, read-only "vanilla" StringsCollection of IP Addresses into the Array
        ServArray = My.Settings.VanillaServerIPList.Cast(Of String)().ToArray
    Else
        'If the user modifiable list of NIST server IP addresses IS NOT null (null = FALSE) then
        'Put the user modifiable StringsCollection of IP Addresses into an Array
        ServArray = My.Settings.ServerIPList.Cast(Of String)().ToArray
    End If

    'Assign null value to LastHost
    LastHost = ""

    'Runs the "If Then" logic that pings all IPs in the array
    'Ping each IP and try to retrieve results
    For Each IP As String In ServArray
        Try
            'Shows each IP in Debug console
            Debug.WriteLine(IP, "IP Addresses")

            If My.Computer.Network.Ping(IP) Then
                LastHost = IP
                Result = GetNISTTime(IP)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Return "Sync Error 0x01"
            MsgBox("There was a sync error while retrieving the updated internet time. Please try again.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Sync Error 0x01")
            Debug.WriteLine("There was a sync error while retrieving the updated internet time. Please try again.", "Sync Error 0x01")
        End Try
    Next

    'No server in list was successful so use system time
    If LastHost = "" Then
        'Return "Sync Error 0x02"
        MsgBox("No server in list returned the time. The sytem time has not been updated.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Sync Error 0x02")
        Debug.WriteLine("No server in list returned the time. The sytem time has not been updated.", "Sync Error 0x02")
        Result = DateTime.UtcNow()
    End If

    Return Result

End Function
```